# Create boolean tensor where values in one tensor are in another

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to find all the places where values from one tensor show up in another tensor. The output should be a Boolean tensor the same shape as the main tensor.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

values = np.random.randint(0, 32, (3, 32))
check_vals = np.random.choice(values.flatten(), 2, False)

main_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(values, dtype=tf.int32)
check_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(check_vals, dtype=tf.int32)

#In numpy I can just do this
np_res = np.isin(values, check_vals)

#and verify it worked by doing:
print (check_vals)
print (values[np_res])

#How to do it in tensorflow??
res = tf.equal(main_tensor, check_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as straight forward as it should be but this is what I got to work.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

values = np.random.randint(0, 32, (3, 32))
check_vals = np.random.choice(values.flatten(), 2, False)

main_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(values, dtype=tf.int32)
check_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(check_vals, dtype=tf.int32)

#In numpy I can just do this
np_res = np.isin(values, check_vals)

#Loop over the check_tensor using tf.map_fn. Have to set output since
#input and output dtypes are different
checks = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.equal(main_tensor, x), check_tensor, fn_output_signature=tf.bool)

#Now we do a reduce_any operation to combine the results from
#each entry in check_tensor
result = tf.reduce_any(checks, axis=0)

print (np.all(result.numpy() == np_res))
```

Comment: Can't you just subtract the two tensors and find the zeros? Edited: I assumed these two tensors were of the same shape.  It looks like that isn't the case.  This is an interesting problem, I will try and find a solution later.

Comment: You can do this by reshaping the main tensor and the check vals tensor such that you can do a broadcasted subtraction.  It would take two operations because in the first pass, you'd find the matching tensors that were in even positions (0 index) and the second pass you'd find the ones in odd positions.  The number of passes is a function of the number of dimensions of the check_vals vector. Then you'd need to find the [0, 0] tensors.  I guess it really depends on the performance sensitivity of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a small enough tensor you can do this without `map()` using broadcasting. It can easily explode in memory if your inputs are large so please be mindful.

```
values = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0, 32, (3, 5)))
check_vals = tf.constant(np.random.choice(values.numpy().flatten(), 2, False))

res = tf.reduce_any(values[:, :, tf.newaxis]==check_vals[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :], axis=-1)
```